# Sources for additional (summonable) creatures in Anima: Beyond Fantasy

Tags: anima-beyond-fantasy

I'm playing a summoner in Anima. I've gone through the book and there is a startling lack of things that I can use to summon - which makes me rather weak, as my main ability doesn't have many options.

Are there more creatures provided elsewhere, and if so, where?

Comment: The [mechanics] tag has been burned and is not to be used anymore.

Comment: Unrelatedly, it is nice to see people playing this game. I was skeptical about it when [Wen-M](http://wen-m.deviantart.com/) first started working on the art for it.

Comment: We are still skeptical due to the lack of material for summoners and casters and a general lack of experience with the system but we are trouping through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a book of monsters, quite extensive.

'Those Who Walked Among Us'.

Probably Gaia, Volume One whould have some examples of monsters, althougt I have not read this one.

Comment: I have recently become aware of this myself, and am kinda sad that I dont have the money to get it.

Comment: Other option is to create your own, unique creatures with the guideline of the core book. You assign a level to the creature, a Gnosis and build it like that. Goes without saying, but the GM should carefully see (or even do them him/her self) that the creatures are balanced for your style of play.

Comment: Yup, a good method is to tell your GM "I want to be able to summon this, this and that", and he will make them for you. Don't do it during a game session, though... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have searched the books and the options are limited, especially at lower levels.
(core, those who walk..., Game master's toolkit, gaia 1) (not sure if you can summon undead/animated-corpse (ud)) (same for (machine) constructs (c/mc)) (not counting Spirit undead)

+-105 - (11+ uncontrollable) - 9 (undead) - (+-10 constructs) = ~75 creaturse

avarage level 4.35 & median 5

- level  0:  2 (1ud)
- level  1:  4 (1ud)
- level  2:  3 (1c)
- level  3:  9.2
- level  4: 10.8 (1c, 1ud/c)
- level  5:  8  (1ud, 1ud/c, 1c)
- level  6: 11.6 (1c, 1mc)
- level  7: 12  (1ud, 1c, 1mc, ud/c, 1ud?)
- level  8:  8  (1mc, 1ud/c)
- level  9:  7  (1mc, 1ud/c)
- level 10:  5.4 (1ud)
- level 11:  3  (gnosis?)
- level 12:  2  (1c)(gnosis?)
- level 13:  2  (gnosis?)
- level 14:  1  (c1?/(gnosis?))
- level 15:  2  (gnosis?!)

---

- level  0: Zombie (ud) / Fiery Salamandere
- level  1: Babelion / Soul Scavenger / Skeleton (ud) / Gnidium Helleborum
- level  2: Ghost, minor / Drone (mc) / Marionette, Lesser (c)
- level  3: Luminary / Shadow / Blatoddea / Cath Flidais / Chichusei / Yinnun / Gwyllgi / Succubus (Daughter of Lilith & -Abrael )
- level  4: Asagiri / Aberration / Animated Armor (c) / Spectral Beast / Stribog / Ghost, major / Hamadryad (8 types) / Child of Baal / Spectral Observer / Ashura Oni, Lesser / Type-005 (ud/c) / Zaqqun
- level 5: Nezuacuatil / Slayer (ud) / Banshee / Hunter (Type-012) (ud/c) / Ignis / Baroque / Marionette, Greater (c) / Medusa / Lesser Oni (2 or more types)
- level 6: Elementals (Sylph / Efreet / Titan / Undine) / Manfeitor / Emeth (c) / Huldra / Technocrat (mc) / Nyx / Manticore / Arctic Chimera / Blood Rose / Shinigami, Lesser Shinigami / Symbiosis (2 sides)
- level 7: Alius / Archchimera / Void Knight (ud) / Cerberus / Sphinx / Ginnungaus / Ginnungaus (gnosis 30) / Humbaba (c) / Nature's Wrath / Carrier, Lesser (mc) / Raziel Archeteypum (Type-100) (ud/c) / Bone Collector / Valkyrie (ud?)

*MOST* OF THE FOLLOWING CAN NOT BE CONTROLED (gnosis 30+)

- level 8: Abomination / Arhiman / Belphe / Ice Maiden / Carrier, Greater (mc) / Necrogolem (Type-042) (ud/c) / Ashura Oni, Greater / Dementia, Lord of Nightmares
- level 9: Hecatondies (c?) / Al-Djinn / Dullahan / Etrien Gnosos / Ghost, Arcane / Praetorian (mc) / Shadow Master / aziel NK-X ver. 1.0 (Type-666) (ud/c)
- level 10: Lord of the Dead (ud) / Shinigami, Greater Shinigami

*ALL* OF THE FOLLOWING CAN NOT BE CONTROLED (gnosis 30+)

- level 11: Behemoth / Infernal Duke / The Shadow of Omega (Omega)
- level 12: Sigma Hecatondies (c) / Seeraphim Potestas

*ALL* OF THE FOLLOWING CAN NOT BE BOUND (gnosis 35+)

- level 13: C'iel Dragon / Gaira Dragon

*ALL* OF THE FOLLOWING CAN NOT BE SUMMONED WITHOUT CONSENT (gnosis 40+)

- level 14: Infinite Orb
- level 15: Filisnogos / Lucifer (Omega) / the Lord of Infinity (Omega)